# Using Navigation Controller in a subview of View based Applicatin

Tags: iphone, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0

Some one please help me with this. I am developing an iPhone app and have stared with View Based Application. I have buttons on my root view screen to take user to other views with their own nibs and classes. On one of those views I need to display a table getting data from SQLite database and then display detail of the selected item depending on the selection from the table. At later stage I also need to add forms to add data.

Now, how to add a Navigation Controller in that view for drill down? Can we convert a View Controller to Navigation Controller just by adding a Navigation bar at the top?

Answer (score 1):

sure
in viewbase application, u can create navigation controller

add the code in delegate.h

```
@interface test24AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    test24ViewController *viewController;
    UINavigationController *nav;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet test24ViewController *viewController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *nav;

@end
```

add this delegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
    nav=[[UINavigationController alloc]init];
        [nav pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];


    [self.window addSubview:nav.view];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

now it will work, u check using nslog(@"%@", self.navigationController); if the result is null then u have problem still.